# Approve the content to go live in SharePoint Publishing Sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have created a site within a SharePoint 2013 Site Collection. I have used a custom master-page that built from an HTML page. This site has several pages. I have added some content to those pages and there are no any issues.

I am using a publishing web site in SharePoint 2013.

But now I want to make some changes and once done that need to send a reminder ( as an email ) to another person to check and verify the content using the same email and save that content in the site permanently.

Different pages must be approved by different approves.

Can this be done using a workflow? If so how and what type of workflow needs to use?

Regards,

Chiranthaka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using a publishing workflow - or called as Approval workflow , there would be a group of permission called as Approvers and when you click on Approve/Reject button the mailer will be sent to those people who are in that Users group.

Comment: If different pages should approve by different approvers then how the workflow should arrange?

Comment: Approval workflow can be trigerred for only one item at a time - which means the publishing will happen for one page/document at a time.
When you trigger the workflow , on the popup you can specify the approvers as well - have you checked the screen?

Comment: OK then my problem was solved. Many thanks for everyone who tried to help me.